# iOS Custom button isn't grayed out

Tags: button

I've noticed that my custom buttons are not grayed out when another view appears; for example an actionsheet or a popover. But a standard button (i.e.: info light) is grayed out.

Here you see an example. The info light is the standard button and the share is a custom button with an image.

[image]

The screen is grayed out when an actionsheet or popover comes up. Notice the difference between the two buttons.

[image]

How can I make my custom button grayed out like the info button?

Thanks!

PS: The grayed out button doesn't correspond to the disabled state!